# Sending Bundle with Fragment Transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

Here is my code that is not working:

// Sending bundle this way:

```
        String topUser = String.valueOf(scores.get(arg2));

        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("userprofile", topUser);

        FragmentTransaction t = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        SherlockListFragment mFrag = new ProfileFragment();
        mFrag.setArguments(data);
        t.replace(R.id.main_frag, mFrag);
        t.commit();
```

// Retrieving this way:

```
        Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        userName = extras.getString("userprofile");
```

Basically, the data isn't received.  Am I on the right track or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should be using the `getArguments()` method of the Fragment class. So put something like the following inside your `Fragment`:

```
Bundle extras = getArguments();
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getArguments()

Comment: just to clarify - calling `getActivity().getIntent().getExtras()` actually works, but you get the "arguments" of the underlying `Activity` and not the `Fragment`s :)

Comment: I cant tell you how long I just spent trying to figure out how to get that from the saved state bundle... I guess because I also happened to be passing a parcelable object — anyway this should be starred